# Error on Launch - MikTeX Console not working

Tags: errors, miktex, console

I just re-installed MiKTeX for the same reason, when I try to launch the console I'm prompted with this message:

"MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the directory 'G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin'."

Details:

Here is a screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud4og.jpg

[image]

To clarify that "USER" is my brother's session we share the same machine we're on a Windows 10

PC Specs:
CPU: i7-4790K 4.00GHz
RAM: 16GB
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce Asus 1080Ti

Comment: go to the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: The picture (screen shot) should be directly put in your question (instead of providing its link)

Comment: Where to find miktex issue tracker please Ulrike Fischer, I'm new to stack exchange sorry Black Mild.

Comment: @BlackMild the OP can not make it an inline image until gets a few more rep points (protection against passers by posting inappropriate images)

Comment: `G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin`: Is the name of the sub-directory `\Instaled` (with a single `l`) and not `\Installed` (with two `l`)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, now I knew that. Anyway, I attached the figure for him.

Comment: @BlackMild so you have, thanks

Comment: @UlrichDiez what does that mean? The issue is that G Volume is locked by my brother using bitlocker thing so I have to wait for him to unlock it for me but once that's done what do I do to go around this issue ?

Comment: I doubt that `G:` needs to be unlocked. I suppose, `G:` has directory "G:\USER\program\Insta**ll**ed\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin"  and not "G:\USER\program\Insta**l**ed\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin". So modification should take place not in the volume but in these places (configuration-files? .tex-files?) where this file-path is used/is erroneously typed with a missing **l**.

Comment: Ok I see, but I re-installed MiKTeX exactly before posting, it was doing the same thing then. Does that have effect?

Comment: One other thing when I first installed MiKTeX before all this malarkey I made sure MiKTeX was installed for "me" alone meaning not all users of my machine, however this issue happened when G: was locked, and as I mentioned I re-installed it yet it still happens, I don't know if this information is helpful but I hope so.

Comment: Do you need to provide a PIN for accessing the volume `G:` in question? If so, then, yes, the volume needs to be "unlocked". (Bitlocker does encrypt the volume and the PIN is needed for decrypting...)

Comment: It's protected by Bitlocker so yes, one more thing I juts remember that the log file has that info in it, "Protected by bitlocker", but my issue is once I take care of this, how do I change that directory ?? Because when I installed MiKTeX I made sure it's installed for me and me alone no one else, and also I didn't install it in C: drive either so this is sort of weird for me. Thanks. =)

Comment: I find it weird that MiKTeX an "open-source distribution of the TeX/LaTeX typesetting system for MS Windows" wants access to video files ???? "Moves\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static" I just can't understand why...

Comment: the miktex issue tracker is here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues.

Comment: I did post there, the mods simply read the log file and closed my issue, "Bitlocker thing..." still thank you for that.

Comment: I suppose MiKTeX does not want access to video files but to ffmpeg which is an encoder/decoder for video files/embedded videos. Maybe ffmpeg is used by the pdf-viewing-module of [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) which comes along with MiKTeX in case there are videos embedded into the .pdf-file. Probably ffmpeg is included in MiKTeX so you can more easily take advantage of features of the [media9](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9)-package and the like.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, and yes probably that's the issue.

Comment: Alright now what I've done is gone full berserk mode and deleted every instance of MiKTeX from my machine, deleted everything in the registry as well, and re-installed it, by the end of the installation it says this Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:
 MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the directory 'G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin\'.
I can share log files of the installation.

Comment: [https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/956](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/956) says: `2021-10-27 16:56:04,498+0100 FATAL main - Windows API error 2150694912: This drive is locked by BitLocker Drive Encryption. You must unlock this drive from Control Panel.`  Seems MiKTeX lacks info for decrypting the bitlocker-encrypted drive `G:` and thus can't access some file it would like to access. Did you try to embed some (video or image--)file stored in the path  `G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin` into your document, using package media9 or the like?

Comment: I don't use that volume the G: volume, I've written lots of documents but never with a video-file in them, I may have done it accidentally but not that I know of

Comment: That issue you sent me, was mine I opened that ticket.

Comment: @RedouaneSaidi In this case I suppose MiKTeX itself for some obscure reason tries and fails to access an ffmpeg-installation which it assumes to be installed in `G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin`. Probably the discussion [Does MikTeXinstall/depend on ffmpeg? #957](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/discussions/957) will enlighten us.

Comment: Alright I unlocked that volume, that file doesn't exist, but fortunately it's working normally I'll restart the computer and see if things stay normal or it goes wonky again. Thank you so much for staying with me <3

Comment: @RedouaneSaidi I know it is your issue. :-)  The point is: With the issue you also submitted a .log-file. That .log-file says that `G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin` cannot be accessed due to bitlocker-issues. And you said that the drive/volume in question is encrypted by bitlocker. So we know why MikTeX attempting to access that drive/directory-path does not work out. But the fundamental question is: Why at all does MiKTeX attempt to access that drive/directory-path?

Comment: Ok so I opened the G: Volume and got MiKTeX working, I did a quick update, I restarted the machine, now the volume is closed again but the error persists, what's weird is that I checked the files and there is no such file I don't know why it's trying to access files that don't exist ?

Comment: Are there any registery files I can delete in order for MiKTeX to forget about it?

Comment: @RedouaneSaidi I don't know.  Probably some totally different piece of software (malware?) corrupted some entries in the Windows-registry that denote file-paths, leading to programs relying on correct registry-values not working any more due to assuming incorrect directory-paths?  Probably it is a bug in MiKTeX?

Comment: Ok so I've done the same thing one last time, deleted MiKTeX from its roots while G: volume was open, everything worked fine, until I restarted the PC again and it's the same issue again, so for now I'm going to work with G: open because I don't have the choice, but I have to find a real solution to this.

Comment: Although regarding the question whether MiKTeX itself needs ffmpeg the developer of MiKTeX did not provide a clear statement but just gave a counterquestion, I assume that no component shipped along with MiKTeX does use/depend on ffmpeg. Thus the real solution might be:If ffmpeg is not installed in the mentioned folder/directory, just remove the corresponding entry from the environment-variable "PATH". Otherwise uninstall ffmpeg, hereby removing the entry from the environment-variable "PATH" and install it in a volume/folder which in any case is unlocked when the system is booted up.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entry "G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin" in the operating-system's(=in Windows 10's) environment-variable whose name is "PATH".

"PATH" is a system-wide variable which lists all directories/folders in which the operating-system shall search for executables in case only the name but not the file-path of the executable in question is provided when calling that executable, e.g., via command-line/shell/shell-script/batch-file/ini-script/whatsoever.

Many sloppy programs trigger the operating-system into attempting to search (and hereby access) all directories/folders listed in the "PATH"-variable in order to use or to find out about the presence of executables provided by other parties.

So does the MiKTeX-installer.

**(There are many scenarios, however, where, instead of searching all directories/folders listed in the "PATH"-variable, it would be sufficient to access/search only specific folders/entries in case they are listed in the "PATH"-variable.**
Nowadays I take this "PATH"-thingie for a security-problem, btw.)

If a directory/folder listed in the "PATH"-variable cannot be accessed/searched due to the volume which it refers to being encrypted and locked, and/or due to the folder/directory in question not existing any more, then such attempts trigger error-messages.

It seems in your system the entry "G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin" was added to the environment-variable "PATH" when installing the program [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in a volume which back then was assigned the drive-letter "G:". ([ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is "a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video".)

Maybe installing the program [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in a volume "G:" took place a long time ago, before attempting to install MiKTeX and long before having attached to the system a drive/volume "G:" which was encrypted with bitlocker.

Nowadays volume "G:" is encrypted by bitlocker.

If the program [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is not installed in the system any more and the entry in the environment-variable is a remainder due to an improper uninstalling-routine, just manually remove this entry from the environment-variable PATH.

If the program [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is still installed in the system, in the mentioned directory on volume "G:", then the program is unusable as long as "G:" is locked/not unlocked and therefore inaccessible.
Therefore in this case I suggest (temporarily) unlocking the volume "G:" and uninstalling ffmpeg, hereby ensuring that the entry is removed from the PATH-variable as well, and installing ffmpeg in a volume either not affected by bitlocker or unlocked in any case when the system is booted up.

In any case if the entry denoting the nowadays encrypted "G:\..." is removed from the environment-variable "PATH", then carrying out MiKTeX will not lead to (error-message-triggering) attempts of accessing the (not-any-more-existing?) directory/folder "G:\USER\program\Instaled\Movies\ffmpeg-20190604-d81913e-win64-static\bin" on the locked volume "G:" while (for whatever reason) searching/examining/attempting to access each directory/folder listed in the "PATH"-variable.

Here is a link to a tutorial on manually editing environment-variables like the "PATH"-variable in Windows 10:

https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10